# Bundler fails with Rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv, shim

I have inherited a rails 2.3.2 application and got it to work using ruby 1.8.7 under rbenv including some old versions of other gems and software.

Now I have generated a Gemfile and try to verify it by runing any bundle comand on it, e.g. bundle check, install, etc. but any of these operations fail. I installed the rbenv bundler plugin which makes it look a little lesss severe but  I still can't figure it out.

```
$ bundle -V
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:846: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:310:in `<module:Bundler>': uninitialized constant Gem::VERSION (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:12:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:4:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:4:in `<main>'
```

My bundler installation:

```
$ which bundle
/usr/bin/bundle
```

Ruby:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
```

Rbenv gives me problems too now:

```
$ rbenv alternatives 
Skipping 1.8.7-debian, it already exists
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:846: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
Skipping 1.9.3-debian, it already exists
```

Isn't there supposed to be a shim for bundler? It seems that bundler is called directly.

I am lost. If anyone could help me with this I would be glad.

p.s.: I also just discovered this:

```
$ rbenv rehash 
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:846: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:310:in `<module:Bundler>': uninitialized constant Gem::VERSION (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:12:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bernhard/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:361:in `require'
    from /home/bernhard/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:361:in `require_and_patch_bundler'
    from /home/bernhard/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:427:in `<main>'
cat: /home/bernhard/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/share/rbenv/bundler/manifest.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.` is not an error - it's a warning. With rbenv bundle should point to `~/.rbenv/shims/bundle`, so it looks like something is misconfigured on your `$PATH`. Can you run `echo $PATH` and post the output?

Comment: This is my path: /usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/bernhard/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games. I appreciate your help.